# Devise and Strong Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, strong-parameters

I would like to know how to integrate both of this gems(devise + Strong Parameters), since strong params will likely be added to the rails core in 4.0

any help is welcome
thanks

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Update for devise 4.x

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:username])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:username])
  end
end
```

---

After adding both gems, devise will work as normal.

Update: With the latest version of Devise 3.x, as described at [devise#strong-parameters](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters), the authentication key (normally the email field), and the password fields are already permitted. However, if there are any additional fields on the signup form, you will need to let Devise know the extra fields to permit. The easiest way to do this is with a filter:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :username
  end
end
```

For Devise 2.x, if you use the safety feature requiring explicitly whitelisting tainted parameters in the user model:

```
include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection
```

the changes needed are found at https://gist.github.com/3350730 which overrides some of the controllers.

Comment: Next answer is better, from my view, since it relay on Devise public API

Comment: That would be because my answer was from over a year ago. I've updated the answer based on the new developments.

Comment: this question is a perfect example of how small is the world, you answered my question with my own gist =D

Comment: This answer no longer works.  You need to use `devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username])`

Answer (score 9):

The easy way is to add a simple before filter in your ApplicationController. If you have different roles and/or other more complex scenario there are other options on the link below:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters

Answer (score 1):

```
before_filter :configure_sanitized_params, if: :devise_controller?

def configure_sanitized_params
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:firstname, :designation_id, :middlename, :previous_experiance_year, :previous_experiance_month, :lastname, :email, :username, :password, :password_confirmation, :previous_experiance, :empid, :dob, :timezone, :doj, :gender, :education, :comments, :locked, :deactivated, :reason, :phone, :deactivated_date, :image) }
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:remove_image, :firstname, :designation_id, :middlename, :lastname, :email, :username, :empid, :dob, :timezone, :doj, :gender, :education, :comments, :locked, :deactivated, :reason, :phone, :deactivated_date, :image) }
end
```

Comment: yeah, this is the new way to do it. the question was asked back in the day when devise hadn't implemented strong parameters on their code.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this one its include nested params permit

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username,:phone])
  # permit nested attributes
  # devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: 
  # [:username,:phone,profile_attributes:[:firstname, :lastname]])
  end
end
```

This will work with rails 4 and 5 devise and rails