# Paperclip gem render avatar upload in different view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

Hi I'm using the [paperclip gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) and currently a user of my website can upload his/her avatar in the edit profile page under my registrations ([devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)) the code for uploading goes like this:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :avatar %><br />
    <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
  </div>
```

Is there a way that I can render this avatar upload in a different view? How do I go about it? I want to place it not in my devise view but my view for the user's profile.

Comment: if you added the `avatar` field to your user model, you can render it like so in your show action, for example: `<%= image_tag(@user.avatar.url) %>`. In case you only want to show the current users avatar, replace `@user` with `current_user`

Comment: I want to render the upload, I have already rendered the image :D

Comment: Ah, i see (: you should be able to open a `<%= form_for current_user, :url => { :action => :update } %>` on your users profile page and place the avatar upload there

Comment: I took the freedom to add it as an answer (:

Comment: I upvoted for you, F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your users profile page, you can place a form with update action for your current user. It could look something like so:

users/registrations/show.html.erb

```
<% if current_user == @user %>
  <%= form_for current_user, url: { :action => :update } do |f| %>
    <!-- ... -->
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :avatar %><br />
      <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
    </div>
    <!-- ... -->
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>        
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to *upload* the avatar in a different view, you can certainly do it.

If you want to do it in your *devise* view, you'll have to edit your database, model and controller.

---

You can set a "profile" action no problem, we do it [here](http://bvc-video.herokuapp.com) (it's only a test app, you could register for free and try it yourself...):

[image]

You must remember that the `User` model is not tied to `Devise` - you can do anything you want with it, regardless of whether it's used for authentication or not.

You can do the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :profile, controller: :users, only: [:index, :update]

#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def update
      current_user.update avatar_params
   end

   private

   def avatar_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:avatar)
   end
end

#app/views/users/index.html.erb
<%= form_for current_user, multipart: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :avatar %><br />
    <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will have to be matched with the appropriate model code etc, but should work to allow you to upload the appropriate avatar.

You can also make the avatar appear in other parts of the app, like this:

[image]

This can be done using the standard Paperclip [image file path helpers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#show-view):

```
<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url %>
```

---

If you wanted to tie the avatar to the registration process, you'll have to edit the devise controller to [allow the parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17736187/1143732):

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:user) << :avatar
  end
end
```

If you have the correct setup in your model, this should allow you to include the avatar upload facility in your Devise registrations view.

Comment: Thanks F, glad to hear people appreciating it!

Answer (score 0):

In you view you can show it like this

```
<%= image_tag(@user.image.url %>
```

or if you have different sizes, then you may render like this

```
<%= image_tag(@user.image.url(:original) %> # :original is image defined in model.
```