# "Unpermitted parameters: name"and "Can't mass assign protected attributes for User: email" Do I need a User controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, devise, controller, mass-assignment

I am using Rails 4 and Devise 3. I have added a custom field of "name." When I submit a name, I receive the "unpermitted parameters: name" and "can't mass assign protected attributes for User: email" errors.

I have been told to add code to a users controller, however Devise did not create one. Am I supposed to create a users_controller.rb on my own, or is there something I am missing here?

My User model looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, #:recoverable,
          :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  #attr_accessible :name, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :email
end
```

As you can see, I have tried to use attr_accessible, but commented it out since it's not supported in Rails 4.

Comment: in the controller, have you permitted those attributes in `post_params` private action?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strong parameters with Rails 4.0 and Devise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16379554/strong-parameters-with-rails-4-0-and-devise)

Comment: @Nithin - In which controller? A user controller? Should I create one?

Comment: @Dylan it will be in a custom Registrations controller - let me write an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devise uses its own controllers to process your data, so you'd ideally add your extra params to those controllers. However, there are a number of ways you can do it

---

From [Devise's Github](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters):

> In case you want to permit additional parameters (the lazy way™) you
>   can do with a simple before filter in your ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :username
  end
 end
```

---

From [Strong parameters with Rails and Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16379554/strong-parameters-with-rails-4-0-and-devise)

```
# config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => 'registrations'}


# controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters

  protected

  # my custom fields are :name, :heard_how
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
      u.permit(:name, :heard_how,
        :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |u|
      u.permit(:name,
        :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Hi, @Rich. Thanks for very detailed reply. Unfortunately I don't have a registrations_controller.rb. In fact, I don't even have a users directory in the controllers folder. Was Devise supposed to create this folder and file automatically? Can I just make it myself?

Comment: Hey Dylan, Devise doesn't make those controllers normally - you have to extend them (hence why it's called as `Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController`). Devise's controllers are hidden, but are called `SessionsController` & `RegistrationsController`. Hope this helps?

Comment: Ah, okay, @Rich. You're definitely helping me to understand what's going on. I have created the user/registrations_controller.rb file and added the code you told me to. I also added the code you mentioned to the routes.rb file. When I try to save a user to the site, I receive an error "uninitialized constant RegistrationsController." What's that about?

Comment: I have managed to get rid of the "uninitialized constant" error by setting the correct path in the routes. Still getting "can't mass assign protected attributes for User: name, email" though.

Comment: The code I created is from the github Gist, so I'm not entirely sure if it's 100% going to work, but let's keep going to get this working

Comment: Have you got your form code we can look at? You might have a problem with the way your params have been constructed. Also it would be good to see your new registrations_controller code -- to see if it's all okay?

Comment: Also, if you want to go to chat, please let me know. I have a custom RegistrationsController we used for developing http://firststop.herokuapp.com - so I've got some code we can definitely use

Comment: I would LOVE to go to chat. Can you move it? I do not have enough reputation @Rich

Comment: Oh dammit - it says you've got too little reputation to chat. I'll see if I can invite you manually

Comment: Is Google chat an option for you? Or Gmail?

Comment: I need 20 reputation to talk in there.

Comment: Okay :( What's your gmail & I'll open a chat

Comment: drichards2013@gmail.com