# Rails 4 + Devise - Unpermitted parameters when updating user's account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, devise

I have the following setup:

**routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users, :path_names => { :controllers => {:omniauth_callbacks => "omniauth_callbacks", :registrations => "registrations"}
```

and `RegistrationController`:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def update
    ...
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:tw_account, :fb_account, :current_password, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

But every time when I try to update the users' data, I get this error message:

> Unpermitted parameters: tw_account, fb_account

But when I create a new account with these two fields, they're saved. How to make them update-able?

Thank you

Comment: You must view this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16379554/strong-parameters-with-rails-4-0-and-devise

This topic must help you.

Answer (score 8):

This works for me, inherit **Devise::RegistrationsController**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update).push(:tw_account, :fb_account)
  end

end
```

You should also remove current_password, password_confirmation and password from parameters because devise already handled these.

Comment: Thank you. It works for me. But what is the difference from:
`devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:tw_account, :fb_account) }`
Why this doesn't work...

Comment: Anybody have a link to where this shows up in the docs? It seems poorly documented

Answer (score 4):

You may probably want to go with

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:tw_account, :fb_account, :current_password, :password, :password_confirmation) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved with changing  `' devise_parameter_sanitizer.for'` with ' `devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit`'

My line works perfectly:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

    protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:name, :last_name, :image,:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
    end
end
```