# Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms) on Devise sign in (sessions create)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, devise

am relatively new to rails. Please forgive me if this is supposed to be obvious.

Am failing to sign in into my account using devise, I keep getting the error invalid email or password,  but they are the ones I used while creating the account. The server doesn't seam to contact the model for information when I look at the logs.

```
    Processing by Businesses::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"PGav1Ca1p0XvayyhzvzN8IVgtHboVhYSTOg2YodI/UUK0VvpdwlmkEUj43hCjEVxgQokocVVMelJxJqMbUc+Dg==", "business"=>{"email"=>"jwaiswa7@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Login"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

That's the response i receive and when the view is being called again, I get the error unpermitted parameter email

```
Processing by Businesses::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"PGav1Ca1p0XvayyhzvzN8IVgtHboVhYSTOg2YodI/UUK0VvpdwlmkEUj43hCjEVxgQokocVVMelJxJqMbUc+Dg==", "business"=>{"email"=>"jwaiswa7@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Login"}
Unpermitted parameter: email
```

Any help on how to go around this is highly appreciated.

Comment: it is your custom controller so Please post the controllers code

Comment: In the controller, am inheriting the Devise sessions Controller..So there is nothing in the controller really..    
`class Businesses::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController


  protected
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    business_dashboard_path
  end


end`

Comment: Please post the codes

Comment: you need to permit the paramters

Comment: in your views you using `:business` why is there any reason for chnage it the resource ?? also please follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16379554/strong-parameters-with-rails-and-devise

Comment: Ok, after permitting the parameter, the unpermited parameters issue is done, but am still failing to sign in..

Comment: what is your resource 'User or Business ?

Comment: Its a business model, added to devise

Comment: then in rails console try `Business.where(email: "jwaiswa7@gmail.com").try(:last).valid_password? "your password"` check it

Comment: I get a response true form the rails console...

Comment: Hi, all, I've found the solution to the problem. Someone had changed the authentication_key form email to something else, So I was failing to sign in.