# NameError (undefined local variable or method `devise_parameter_sanitizer'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, controller

I'm using devise for user authentication. However, when a user tries to create an account I am getting this error:

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `devise_parameter_sanitizer'
```

This is what my devise registrations controller looks like:

```
def sign_up_params
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up)
end
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yeah I'm getting the same behavior, did you find any solution to this?

Comment: I'm also experiencing this

Comment: could you add the bundle exec gem list output

Answer (score 6):

try to use rails4 branch

```
gem 'devise', github: 'plataformatec/devise', branch: 'rails4'
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the devise open issues on Github i found this: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2372 - seem to do the trick for me. note that this is probably a rails 4 issue.

Comment: Experiencing it on rails 3.2.x

Comment: are you on the latest devise version?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who ends up here with error

```
undefined method `<<' for {}:ActionController::Parameters
```

you need to upgrade to Devise 3.1.0.rc as in [this comment](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2574?source=cc#issuecomment-22809071)
which basically means using master branch version

```
gem 'devise', git: 'git://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git'
```

hope I help some lost souls as I was for last half an hour.

Answer (score 1):

The latest released Gem for Devise at the time of writing is 2.2.4. This does not include the `devise_parameter_sanitizer` method, hence the error you are seeing.

You are probably following the manual for Devise at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise. The section on Rails 4 and Strong Parameters has been added recently.

You have a few options:

1. Get the latest master version of Devise using bundler, so that the `devise_parameter_sanitizer` method is available:

   `gem 'devise', :git => 'git://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git'`
2. Don't apply `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection` to your User model, so strong parameters are not even used. More info here: [Devise and Strong Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904105/devise-and-strong-parameters)
3. Override the required Devise controllers directly. See here: https://gist.github.com/kazpsp/3350730