# strong parameters in rails 4.0 simple Devise implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, attributes, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I've gone through the documentation but I still can't get my head around the syntax/formatting.

I am pretty new in rails. I have this in my model:

```
attr_accessible :email, :username
```

Because of the changes in rails 4.0 this need to be moved over to my controller.

If I put this in my controller would it be correct(This is what I think documentation says to do but not sure if I interpreted correctly):

```
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :username
  end
```

To me something like this makes more sense, can I do this?:

```
protected
  def permitted_paramters
    params.require(:username, :email).permit(:username, :email)
  end
```

Any suggestions appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904105/devise-and-strong-parameters

Comment: You don't need `attr_accessible` in Rails 4 ;)

Comment: @RichPeck so I should just leave it off completely and not do anything in my controllers? What do you mean?

Comment: Rails 4 uses `strong_params`, meaning you don't need any reference to `attr_accessible` any more! You should remove from your controllers

Comment: Are you sure, in the documentation it says we need to move our attr_accessible to our controllers or the equivalent of it(protected, permitted params, etc). I'm extremely confused...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it would make more sense to do a `params.require` like everywhere else in your controllers you cannot do so here with Devise because:

- Devise would need to know how you called your method (here `permitted_parameters`)
- You don't want to filter these parameters for every controller

That is why you need to use Devise's `devise_parameter_sanitizer` and make sure to apply it only if you are on a `devise_controller?`.

---

As a side note, in your second example:

```
params.require(:username, :email).permit(:username, :email)
```

The `require` method should not take a list of attributes but the name under which attributes are grouped. On a different controller it should rather look like this:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email)
```

This would allow the following parameters:`user[username]=Joe&user[email]=joe@example.org`

Comment: So was my interpretation of the documentation correct, would my first piece of code work or would I have to substitute some parameters somewhere? No where in that code does it say username or email so that is why it's not too intuitive to me.

Comment: Yes your first piece of code should work but it is only needed if you ask your users for more info than `email` and `password` on signup. If users need to enter a `username`, then you need to add this.

Comment: There is a password confirmation field as well but that is aprt of the password and shouldn't require this either correct?