# My model doesn't save others field in addition to those of Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm developing a web application with Rails and I'm using Devise gem. I added a field in Devise registration view but when I sign up a user, in the database only that field is empty. Am I missing something? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's because strong params was introduced in Rails 4 http://stackoverflow.com/a/11999563/1500195

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Devise strong parameter sanitizer. Just add following lines to your `application_controller.rb`.

```
  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :first_name
  end
```

and call this `configure_permitted_parameters` method before filter for devise controller using `before_filter`.

```
   before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
```

Ref: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters