# How do I get Devise 3.4 to permit Parameters Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

### Suggestions on how to improve this question are welcome

I added 3 things to the Devise user after generating it.

```
t.integer  "role"
t.string   "firstname"
t.string   "lastname"
```

At User Signup these parameters are permitted and user is created correctly.

When a user tries to edit their account the "firstname" and "lastname" values can be changed fine but when a user tries to change their role on their /users/edit page, no error is given, flash says "account updated successfully" but the role value have not changed.

From /log/development.log showing all 3 parameters as unpermitted, if this really is the case I don't know why the other two can be updated.

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"LnVPFFJKV+RtnB21ZUGr4HF1siVcEuT/BRXaLVkch1nWQXiGRFVGhdWchlQSZ9A7mFgKX2njEjCbqR4CHp5hmQ==", "user"=>{"role"=>"worker", "firstname"=>"asdfDe Wet", "lastname"=>"Blomerus", "email"=>"dewet@blomerus.org", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Update"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.8ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 6]]
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.4ms)[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
Unpermitted parameters: role, firstname, lastname
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 84ms (ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)
```

/config/initializers/devise_permitted_parameters.rb

```
module DevisePermittedParameters
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters
  end

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << [:firstname, :lastname, :role]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << [:firstname, :lastname, :role]
  end

end

DeviseController.send :include, DevisePermittedParameters
```

Relevant parts of /app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(secure_params)
    redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User updated."
  else
    redirect_to users_path, :alert => "Unable to update user."
  end
end

private

def secure_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:role, :firstname, :lastname)
end
```

The update action never runs, I can completely comment it out and nothing changes.

Comment: Guess this will help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904105/devise-and-strong-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what works for me with devise:

I change the users/registrations_controller.rb

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, only: [:create]
  before_filter :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

  def create
   super
  end

  # GET /resource/edit
  def edit
    super
  end

  # PUT /resource
  def update
    super
  end

  # DELETE /resource
   def destroy
       super
   end

  protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
      u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :user_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :avatar, :avatar_cache)
    end
end

def configure_account_update_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update)do |u|
      u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :user_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :avatar, :avatar_cache)
  end
end
```

I don't define any update action in the users_controller.rb . It is not needed. Also, I don;t use any type of module that you are defining and it works fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. I didn't have a `registrations_controller.rb` defined so I tried creating it in `app/controllers` or creating an `app/controllers/users` folder and putting it in there. In either case the code doesn't get executed or change anything. How are you getting your requests to use this controller? Did you change the routes file or something else?

Comment: devise will generate these controllers for you if you type into the terminal:

Comment: rails generate devise:controllers scope     => scope being users or whatever you named your model

Comment: the devise documentation will guide you through all of this https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: Thanks for your patience @nate-beers I didn't understand what part of the documentation I was needing to understand until I read your answer and went back to it.